# Unity : apk vs aab for the same scene

Tags: unity, android

I'm new to Unity , i use mac os catalina , unity 2019.4 and build for android/mobile.

I downloaded a unity project from internet. It's already in format of unity project. so i just copy it into my unity folder. THere's only 1 scene there. I can load , run and built with no problem. It created 160mb of .APK file. But now i need to bring this project into my other project (let's name it B project ). Basically i only need to bring that single scene (and all its linked assets) into that B project. What is the proper way to do this ?

Last time, what i did was: i export the whole things as package then imported it into my B project. When i open the scene  , i can run and build with no problem. But it create .AAB rather than .APK and size is 300mb (2x of the previous APK). Is this big size become the reason it become AAB ?

Can someone tell me what's wrong ? why the size is doubled when i just build the same scene. Does unity build includes unused asset ? because in B project there's already asset from my other scenes. What is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: There are a lot of factors in project B that can influence its build size, including its build settings, graphics quality, which scenes are being built, whether you use a Resources folder, what packages or plugins you've included, etc. To help you diagnose the specific issue, it would help if you can walk us through the steps to reproduce this problem starting with two empty projects - that way we can isolate the exact differences that are in play, and eliminate the ones that aren't.

Comment: Thanks , will check that. But why it became .aab ? i tried a small simple cube scene and still it create aab rather than apk .

Comment: [The apk format is obsolete. aab is the new file format for Android apps.](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle)

Comment: @Philipp it looks like that alone could account for the size difference, if the aab is including all the content needed to build an apk for two different devices that each need their own code and asset versions. Want to share it as an answer?

Comment: @DMGregory I never even built an Android game from Unity before, so I don't feel qualified to do so.

Comment: in Unity, is there any setting to change so my project will output apk rather than aab ? My device having problem with aab. How to switch back so my project will output .apk ?

Comment: Presumably you searched [Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html) and [published updates about exporting AABs](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/10/03/support-for-android-app-bundle-aab-in-unity-2018-3-beta/) and found the "Build App Bundle" checkbox in the Build Settings window?

Comment: Note that .apk is not actually obsolete for Android apps, but is discouraged in favor of .aab specifically for release to the Google Play store. Aab files are relatively useless when side-loading, providing direct download links, or releasing to a different App Store. Also, in my experience, aab files tend to be about the same size as a universal apk generated by Unity (sometimes even slightly smaller). Certainly not double.